# Unable to install any packages even after enabling remi or adding other mirrors

Tags: php, centos7, yum, packages

I'm trying to install the `php-xml` package. I've tried various solutions and contacted support about this issue yet the following still prompts whenever i'm trying to install the `php-xml` package.

My system is CentOS 7 With DA 1.53

The following message returns:

```
sudo yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: ftp.nluug.nl
* expel: ftp.nluug.nl
* extras: ftp.nluug.nl
* remi-php56: remi.mirror.wearetripple.com
* remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetripple.com
* updates: ftp.nluug.nl
No package php-xml available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Does anyone have any idea? Support noted to also add the remi mirror but to no avail.

Comment: php version ? Please check available pkg .  `yum --enablerepo=remi  search php `
try with `yum --enablerepo remi install php-xml`

Comment: The enablerepo remi install command gives the same error; I got both php 7.1 & 5.6 installed.

Comment: Check "exclude" directives in yum.conf

Comment: No php is excluded in the directive, should I post the entire contents here?

Comment: @RDAxRoadkill please check - https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-centos/ might helpful

Comment: I will check said link, and also overlooked the exclude, the exclude lists `apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*` I guess I also should remove the `php*`

Comment: Turns out the exclude directives @Remi Collet mentioned was the solution, you can post that as an answer if you'd like.